# How do I update a Collection in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have an object called "Document" that has a one-to-many relationship with "DocumentPersonCc". I am trying to change one or more of these collections in my code, but Hibernate is not calling the update query when I expect it.  It does call the update query when I change one of the regular fields (like the document subject), but even then it does not persist any of the one-to-many changes within the database.  What do I need to change in order to get it to work?

Getter and setter for DocumentPersonCc:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "document")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL, comparator = DocumentPersonCc.class)
public SortedSet<DocumentPersonCc> getDocumentPersonCcs() {
    return this.documentPersonCcs;
}

public void setDocumentPersonCcs(
        SortedSet<DocumentPersonCc> documentPersonCcs) {
    this.documentPersonCcs = documentPersonCcs;
}
```

Update Code:

```
public Document updateCcs(Document document) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Document oldD = (Document) session.load(Document.class, document.getId());
    Hibernate.initialize(oldD.getDocumentPersonCcs());
    oldD.setDocumentPersonCcs(document.getDocumentPersonCcs());
    session.update(oldD);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    document = this.returnDocument(document.getId());
    Hibernate.initialize(document.getDocumentPersonCcs());
    return document;
}
```

DocumentPersonCc's Document getter and setter:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "DocumentsId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
protected Document getDocument() {
    return this.document;
}

public void setDocument(Document document) {
    this.document = document;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "document")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL, comparator = DocumentPersonCc.class)
public SortedSet<DocumentPersonCc> getDocumentPersonCcs() {
    return this.documentPersonCcs;
}
```

Use cascade to update child mapping

Answer (score 1):

use cascade in your Document entity class. `

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "document")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL, comparator = DocumentPersonCc.class)
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}) 
public SortedSet<DocumentPersonCc> getDocumentPersonCcs() {
    return this.documentPersonCcs;
}
```

` Then when you save or update collection when you save or update document entity.

Comment: Great! This works perfectly, except that if the updated collection contains entries that are already in the DB I get an exception: "org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session."  I tried doing a "clear()" on Document.DocumentPersonCcs, updating it, and then setting the new collection and updating it again, but I still get the same error. Do I have to iterate through and delete each item, or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: To clarify the above comment, I want to completely replace the old collection with the new collection.  Setting will add elements from the new collection that do not exist in the old collection, but it will throw an exception on elements that exist in both, and it will not remove elements that exist in the old collection but not in the new collection.

Comment: then you have to use merge() method instead of update.  because if the season contain more  than one object from entity we have to merge the objects .

Comment: The merge() method does not throw the exception, but it still does not remove items that are not present in the new collection, and it adds a duplicate of items that are present in both the old and new collections.  For instance, if oldDocument has a collection containing (a, b) and newDocument has the collection set as (a), after I merge the old document contains (a, a, b), whereas I just want it to contain (a) (the same as newDocument).

Comment: Sorry, the above comment is erroneous.  What I meant to say was: The merge() method does not throw the exception, but it still does not remove items that are not present in the new collection, and it won't add new items.  For instance, if oldDocument has a collection containing (a, b) and newDocument has the collection set as (a), after I merge the old document contains (a, b), whereas I just want it to contain (a) (the same as newDocument).  If newDocument has collection (c), it throws an exception: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists.

Comment: try to use saveorupdate() method. because you have new objects in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

In your Document.java add one method as

```
 public void addDocumentPersonCc(DocumentPersonCc documentPersonCc) {
    documentPersonCc.setDocument(this);
    documentPersonCcs.add(documentPersonCc);
 }
```

Now change your updateCcs method as

```
public Document updateCcs(Document document) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Document oldD = (Document) session.load(Document.class, document.getId());
    Hibernate.initialize(oldD.getDocumentPersonCcs());
    SortedSet<DocumentPersonCc> documentPersonCcsList = document.getDocumentPersonCcs();
    //Iterate this documentPersonCcsList

    {
        // add oldD.addDocumentPersonCc(Value from Iterator);
    }    
    session.update(oldD);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    document = this.returnDocument(document.getId());
    Hibernate.initialize(document.getDocumentPersonCcs());
    return document;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I had pretty much exactly this problem today. We're using a very old Hibernate version (5.4.x) so I don't know how relevant this is to newer versions.

The following worked for me:

- Adding `orphanRemoval = true` to the `@OneToMany` annotation, together with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`. This is what deletes missing rows.
- Using `Session.merge(parentObject)`, where `parentObject` is the Document in this case. Needed to handle existing rows correctly.
- Making sure existing DocumentPersonCc objects have their `@Id` property set correctly to prevent duplicate insertions. I had to write some logic to identify these in the input and set the correct IDs, but it was fairly simple. It's not included in the code below.

Document class:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "document", orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL, comparator = DocumentPersonCc.class)
public SortedSet<DocumentPersonCc> getDocumentPersonCcs() {
    return this.documentPersonCcs;
}
```

DocumentPersonCc class:

```
@Id
//Other Hibernate annotations...
public int getDocumentPersonCcId() {
    return this.documentPersonCcId;
}
```

Update method:

```
public Document updateCcs(Document document) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Document oldD = (Document) session.load(Document.class, document.getId());
    Hibernate.initialize(oldD.getDocumentPersonCcs());

    //The changed rows:
    oldD.getDocumentPersonCcs().clear();
    oldD.getDocumentPersonCcs().addAll(document.getDocumentPersonCcs());
    session.merge(oldD);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    document = this.returnDocument(document.getId());
    Hibernate.initialize(document.getDocumentPersonCcs());
    return document;
}
```

The `orphanRemoval` property is described [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-delete-child-entities/).